# Static web sites are never memory intensive?

Tags: performance, apache, http, server

I used httperf to fire up requests to a VM that runs an apache http server. The server hosts 10,000 static html pages. The VM has 4GB memory.

I had 6 phyiscal machines issue 600 requests/s to the VM. What I found is the VM's memory was never saturated. Even when I increase the request rate, and the response rate never grows any more, I ran top commmand in the VM to see the memory utilization, which never exceeds 2.5GiB.

Q1. I guess an apache server hosting static pages are never memory intensive?

Q2. To benchmark apache server, what dynamic web site do you often use? Like an open source php site?

Edit: 
I did not mention the html file sizes before. It was 2KB pages on average.

Comment: It doesn't need a lot of memory if it's just streaming file content to http connection. However, each connection requires some overhead, and if you have too many concurrent connections, apache may eventually collapse.

Comment: Obviously your Apache setup is hitting some setting limit before you run out of physical resources. Have you tried tuning Apache parameters for high traffic? see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html

Comment: @Rage. You are right. The default apache setting is has limits on the performance. I will post my tuning soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my apache server is not tuned to be the best performance. By default setting of the `mpm_prefork` module is not tuned for the highest throughput. I increased the parameters to be like below:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
          ServerLimit           430
        StartServers                     5
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers          10
        MaxRequestWorkers         430
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   50000
</IfModule>
```

Since the machine has 4GB RAM, assuming each worker consumes 2M memory, then the max worker number is set to be 430. Note that we need to specifiy `ServerLimit` directive here otherwise it will complain when I start apache.

Edit:

1. Serving 2KB html pages are not memory intensive. Using the `top` command I saw that each `www-data` process consumes 0.2% memory. So 430 process should be 0.2*430% = 86%. But it is way less than that because the resource accounting in `top` does not include share shared memory and thus is not accurate. Using `smem -u` command I saw the meomry usage (USS and PSS) by user `www-data` is much smaller.
2. I tried putting a few randomly generated 5MB files in the server instead. But the memory utilization is almost the same as with 2KB pages. The response time is larger thought, because transferring large files takes longer. Using 5MB files basically saturates the network instead of the memory!
3. Finally I decided to use [php test pages](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472431). I created 12 of them (e.g., 1.php, 2.php, etc.). Each page simply prints `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. In this way, each page exercises some CPU and memory. I saw the memory usage increased to almost 1.8GB.
4. It turns out that **setting the `MaxRequestWorker` to 430 does NOT always yield the best performance**! More specifically, in the case of using php test pages (Point #3), setting it to 32 yields the same throughput (i.e., responses/s) as 430 processes, but 200ms less in average response time! In other words, **having fewer request workers makes the server more responsive**!